# How to calculate the total value of two column from 3 different tables?

Tags: mysql, addition

For example,I have 3 tables;
table1:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
+-------+
```

table2:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     3 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
+-------+
```

table3:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     1 |
+-------+
```

I want to calculate table1.count+table2.count+table3.count, to get the result,table_right:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     5 |  (1+3+1=5)
|     1 |  (0+0+1=1)
|     0 |  (0+0+0=0)
|     0 |  (0+0+0=0)
|     4 |  (3+0+1=4)
+-------+
```

However, if I use command :

```
 select table1.count+table2.count+table3.count as total
from table1,table2,table3;
```

The result will become to:

```
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     5 |
|     4 |
|     4 |
|     4 |
|     7 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     4 |
|     4 |
|     4 |
|     7 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     4 |
|     3 |
|     3 |
|     3 |
|     6 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     3 |
|     3 |
|     3 |
|     6 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
|     5 |
|     4 |
|     4 |
|     4 |
|     7 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
+-------+
```

This is not the result i want, If I try

```
select distinct table1.count+table2.count+table3.count as total
from table1,table2,table3;
```

I will get:

```
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     5 |
|     4 |
|     7 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     3 |
|     6 |
|     0 |
+-------+
```

Still isn't the result I want. How could i do to get table_right?

Comment: does this column share a common id or something you can group by?

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no correspondence between rows unless you have columns to express that relationship.

Comment: Do you mean to add some rowID to each table? How to add rowID with auto increasing num for each table?

Comment: @josegomezr  I can choose to add a common id, like row id or something. But how to add that?

Comment: if you add a common id (lets call id rowId and lets assume it has the same name on every table), then its way easier, just `SELECT t1.count + t2.count + t3.count as total FROM table1 as t1 left join table2 as t2 using (rowId) left join table3 as t3 using (rowId)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add a common id (lets call id rowId and lets assume it has the same name on every table),

```
SELECT t1.count + t2.count + t3.count AS total 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 using (rowId) 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 using (rowId)
```

if you not have those ids, all i can think about its summing all t1 then all t2 then all t3 and finally add the results together.

```
SELECT t1+t2+t3 as total 
FROM (SELECT (SELECT SUM(count) from table1) as t1,
        (SELECT SUM(count) from table2) as t2,
        (SELECT SUM(count) from table3) as t3
    )
```

Check out this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa80c2/3)

**EDIT (2)**

to add `rowId` just alter the tables:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN rowId int not null auto_increment primary key;
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN rowId int not null auto_increment primary key;
ALTER TABLE table3 ADD COLUMN rowId int not null auto_increment primary key;
```

Comment: how to add row id to these three tables?

Comment: ALTER TABLE <table1> ADD COLUMN rowId int not null;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<test1> ADD COLUMN rowId int not null' at line 1         My original need is that HOW TO ADD ROWID into table1,table2,table3 and let them has been inserted with INCREASING num?